# uploading yii advanced application from local developement server to a live server?

Tags: php, upload, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How to upload my vendor folder to live as while commiting the project to bitbucket. It ignores the vendor folder of yii2 advanced application tamplate.

i don't have composer access on server as its shared hosting which doesn't allow me to access the terminal via SSH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete '/vendor' from your .gitignore file. Also some components can contain .git or own gitignore.

Comment: but i wonder is this the proper way to upload the application to live server?

Comment: Imho production shouldn't generate some code.  I use this method. I update composer components only on dev server, becouse i want to control it.